# Tracking Form Submission Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to track generic visits and form submissions from www.myurl.com/submission and for that I have setup 3 tags in google tag manager:

Google Analytics - for generic analytics stuff

Rule:

```
{{url}} matches RegEx .*
```

Form Listener - to trigger gtm.formSubmit

Rule:

```
{{url}} matches RegEx .*
```

Track Form submission - to trigger an analytics event to be tracked in analytics

Rule:

```
{{url}} contains /submission 
{{event}} equals gtm.formSubmit
```

Currently Google Analytics see's the form submission and tracks a goal when I publish the tag (even if I use incognito mode), but when I tried from a different computer/different account, it doesn't track the GA event triggered by "Track form submission.
Also, if I email the preview/debug page to someone it triggers the event, but once they exit that mode, it stops triggering it. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share URL with the published tag?

Comment: I can only publish code since its behind a login wall. What do you suspect might be happening? problem with the way tag manager is implemented or form submission?

Answer (score 1):

Pedro, the preview/debug mode work only locally - that is, **the same computer, same browser**. If everything seems to work (also use [GA Debug in Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en), publish the container and see if everything works live. If not, try to fiddle around a bit.

A personal suggestion -- sometimes *Click* listener is a better choice and it's more flexible. Using *element* or custom JS macros gives you all the flexibility you need and you could simply track the conversions as the clicks on submit button.

Comment: Everything works in debug mode, but not when published. The event needs to be published once the form is submitted successfully so clicking a button is not a good solution I am afraid. Thanks for the answer tho.

Comment: You can share a container preview now, see: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107056?hl=en#share